# Definition of limits at infinity in higher dimensions using sequences

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Im studying multivariable calculus and stumbled up an alternate way to talk about limits at infinity since one dimensional definition is of no use. So for $\mathbb{R^n}$ with $n \geq 2$, we let $\{a_n\}_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and we define $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$ if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||a_n|| = \infty$. Can we write this definition in terms of quantifiers as we did in single variable calculus? Im providing my quantified definition if you can double check it $$ \forall M > 0 \quad \exists N > 0 \quad \text{ s.t. } \quad n > N \implies ||a_n|| > M$$ Im still having some tourble wraping my head around it. Looking for alternate explanantion or laymen term answers as well as an example would make understanding it thorough.

EDIT: im considering $||x_n||$ to be the norm. (btw what would a norm of a sequence look like? I know what it looks like for vectors but norm of a sequence seems tricky to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The "s.t." should be $n > N \implies \|a_n\| > M$.

Since you are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ each $a_i$ has $n$ components, so the norm is just $\|a_i\| = \sqrt{a_{i1}^2 + a_{i2}^2 + \cdots + a_{in}^2}$.

Comment: so essentially when we say the norm of a sequence approaches infinity, we mean that $\sqrt{a_{i1}^2 + a_{i2}^2 + \cdots + a_{in}^2}$ just gets larger and larger as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @UnKnoWnZ Yes exactly. In plain words, the points get farther and farther away from the origin.